# Migrate Magnolia from Enterprise Edition to Community Edition

Tags: magnolia

Is it possible to migrate Magnolia 5.5 from Enterprise Edition to Community Edition. We have been using Magnolia Enterprise Edition Pro with multisite und commercetools module. We do not need any Professional Edition features and want to keep on our web presence on Magnolia.

Mit freundlichen Grüßen
Alexander Fuchs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use community licence as long as you don't have any enterprise modules in the webapp. That being said, multisite is an enterprise feature so you have to replace it one way or the other.

Cheers,

Ilgun

Comment: do I have to remove the config nodes (multisite, workflow)? Grüß Alex

Comment: We generally don't have the notion of uninstalling so you most likely need to do it on your own yes. Maybe have a look at the modules and what they bootstrap or modify from the default installation. That's a cumbersome process, I wish you good luck :)